# How to change URL structure - Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I want to change a structure of URL using CodeIgniter `routes`. Here is my URL

http://example.com/user/edit/username (**E.g controller/method/parameter**)

and I want to change to:

http://example.com/user/username/edit (**E.g controller/parameter/method**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try like this...

```
$route['user/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(.*)'] = 'user/$2/$1';
```

Comment: And how to change this url **domain.com/products/view/parameter** to **domain.com/product/parameter**.

Comment: @user3740316 if the answer fit your needs. Please accept it.